# Getting empty result if there is 'null' value in CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null

I expected to get full name without middle initial if there is no middle name, but if column "M_NAME" is Null, the select statement returns empty. How can i solve this?

```
   SELECT CONCAT(`Employee`.`F_NAME`, ' ', LEFT(`Employee`.`M_NAME`, 1), '. ', `Employee`.`L_NAME`) FROM `ccms`.`Employee` WHERE HR_ID = '223';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CONCAT` returns `NULL` if any argument is null.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)  You can solve this by making sure that no null argument is null by wrapping any nullable column in either `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` (the latter can take more than two arguments).

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(
        IFNULL(F_NAME, ''),
        ' ',
        IFNULL(CONCAT(LEFT(M_NAME, 1), '. '), ''),
        IFNULL(L_NAME, '')
    )
FROM
    ccms.Employee
WHERE
    HR_ID = '223';
```

What this does is replace `NULL` column values with an empty string, which is probably your intent.  Note that I updated the selection of `M_NAME` so that the period is only added if the value is not null by using this very behavior.

EDIT: You can use backticks and qualify column names if you want, but it's not necessary for this exact query.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`Employee`.`F_NAME`, ' ', COALESCE(LEFT(`Employee`.`M_NAME`, 1), ''), '. ', `Employee`.`L_NAME`) FROM `ccms`.`Employee` WHERE HR_ID = '223';
```

Comment: Yeah that will work, but it will be kind of ugly for people with a `NULL` middle name; i.e. "Bobby . Tables".  It does address the immediate issue, however.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IFNULL()`.

Any place you have a possibly NULL field, wrap it with IFNULL(whatever, '') and then you'll get an empty string instead of a result-killing NULL.

Answer (score -1):

another simple solution is use **CONCAT_WS**. It will work defenitely.

> SELECT
>       CONCAT_WS(''
>       F_NAME,
>       '',
>       LEFT(M_NAME, 1),
>       L_NAME)         FROM
>       ccms.Employee WHERE    HR_ID = '223';